# swagger error: Conflicting schemaIds: Duplicate schemaIds detected for types A and B

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, asp.net-web-api2, swashbuckle

Using Web API and using swashbuckle to generate swagger documentation,
I defined two different classes with the same name in two different namespaces. when I open swagger page in my browser it says

> Conflicting schemaIds: Duplicate schemaIds detected for types A and B. See the config setting - "UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds" for a potential workaround

full message:

> 500 : {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Conflicting schemaIds: Duplicate schemaIds detected for types A and B. See the config setting - \"UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds\" for a potential workaround","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":" at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry.CreateRefSchema(Type type)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry.CreateInlineSchema(Type type)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry.b__1f(JsonProperty prop)\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry.CreateObjectSchema(JsonObjectContract jsonContract)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry.CreateDefinitionSchema(Type type)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(Type type)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.CreateOperation(ApiDescription apiDesc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItem(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetSwagger>b__4(IGrouping`2 group)\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String rootUrl, String apiVersion)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()"} http://localhost:24215/swagger/docs/v1

I don't want to change my classes' names. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I finally found a way in swagger configs. Go to `App_Start\SwaggerConfig.cs` file and under `EnableSwagger` lambda expression add this line:

```
c.SchemaId(x => x.FullName);
```

Full code is like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        // your configs...

        c.SchemaId(x => x.FullName);

        // other configs...
    })
    .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
        // ....
    });
```

Comment: I have provided my Swagger.json file to my clients. If I change accordingly to the above, will this change break the current consumers of my API?

Comment: This is the correct answer when using asp.net framework. You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/tree/5489aca0d2dd7946f5569341f621f581720d4634#usefulltypenamesinschemaids).

Answer (score 178):

Every class in the swagger JSON must have a unique schemaId.

Swashbuckler tries to just use the class name as a simple schemaId, however if you have two classes in different namespaces with the same name (as you do) this will not work.

As the error suggests, you can use the config setting "UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds*" for a potential workaround (Update: not available in recent versions)

In newer versions you can achieve the same behavior via options.**CustomSchemaIds**(x => x.FullName).

Here is an example:

```
   services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
   {
       //your custom configuration goes here

...

  // UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds replacement for .NET Core
       options.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
   });
```

for more information http://wegotcode.com/microsoft/swagger-fix-for-dotnetcore/

Comment: if in case any is here from aspnetzero or aspnetboilerplate or abp community. Same soulution applies just add option to  services.AddSwaggerGen when you enable swagger

Comment: Will UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds  cause breaking change for clients as short ClassName will be replaced with long Namespace.ClassName?

Comment: That seems to break the xml comments and nothing is displayed as schema. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I stil get an error because I use class in a class, so the output contains '+'
                            
My solution: CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName?.Replace('+', '-');

Answer (score 34):

I am using Asp.net Core 2.1. This error resulted when I tried to show Swagger UI.

I solved the problem this way:

In `Starup.cs`, in `ConfigureServices()` add `c.CustomSchemaIds(i => i.FullName);`

see example below:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Title = "ASP.NET Core 2.1+ ConsumerApp API",
                Version = "v1"
            });
            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            c.CustomSchemaIds(i => i.FullName);
        });
```

Answer (score 16):

If you comment out or add:

```
c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
```

In that section, it seems to do same thing.

Comment: In the recent versions UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds is not available. 
Use  c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);  instead

Comment: no longer compatible

Answer (score 14):

For Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.2.1 (on .NET Core 3.1), the Swashbuckle configuration API seems to lack the options described in the older solutions. Instead, the following change in the `Startup.cs` worked for me:

```
  services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
  {
     // Existing configuration

     // Tweak to the Schema generator
     c.SchemaGeneratorOptions = new SchemaGeneratorOptions {SchemaIdSelector = type => type.FullName};
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

If your model contains generic types, consider using `Type.ToString()` instead of `Type.FullName` to get rid of assembly information generated for generic parameter type and make your schema ids more consistent.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());
});
```

Example showing the difference on `List<string>`:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<string>).FullName);
Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<string>).ToString());

// Output:
//    System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
//    System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Comment: Would there be a big problem if one of the types already has ToString defined on it? Or if a developer came in and did that later?

Comment: @Chris You generally override `ToString` in the class, but you can't (easily) override `Type.ToString`. So, no, not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was just with nested classes, and I didn't want to show the full namespace of my classes, so I just remove the namespace from the start of the fullname, which still fixes nested classes as they are output like `Order_OrderItem`.

```js
options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName.TrimStart(type.Namespace + "."));
```

Comment: .Replace(type.Namespace + ".", "") worked for me, TrimStart threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using generic types in your payloads and you are using a Nswag proxy client, you should consider doing this.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString().Replace("`1", ""));
});
```

The reason is to avoid this type of output when you are using Nswag.

[image]

Replace("`1", "") will format generic types and result in a cleaner client:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had 2 of the same classes in my 2 microservice projects (A, and B).

When I opened the **dependencies** folder in project(A), I found that I added the other project(B) as a reference to this project by mistake.

After **removing the dependency between my two projects** the conflict was solved.

Comment: Did you have the same error though? I feel this answer is hard to relate to the question.