# swagger swashbuckle does not support nested class as action method parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using asp.net 5

I have two model class, which are nested, both of the inner class are named `Command`

```
public class EditModel
{
   public class Command
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Info { get; set; }
   }
}
```

and

```
public class CreateModel
{
    public class Command
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my Controller class has two methods

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PutData(CreateModel.Command model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult PostData(EditModel.Command model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Since for both Put and Post's query I am using nested class both name `Command`, Swagger will return the following error

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "PUT Test" for actions -
> TestSwagger.Controllers.TestController.PutData
> (TestSwagger),TestSwagger.Controllers.TestController.PostData
> (TestSwagger). Actions require a unique method/path combination for
> Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable`1
> apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String
> documentName, String host, String basePath)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Swagger will work, if I change one of the Command model name to something different.
Yet, I believe this nested class model name is legit and should work with swagger also.  If there a way to work around this.  Thanks

Comment: Yes that is strange, the type of the arguments should not mater, and the error is `Conflicting method/path combination` do you have custom paths defined?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I do not have a custom path defined. So, both Put and Post have the same route.  I just created a new project from Visual Studio and selected the Web Api .Net 5 Template.  Then added the two model classes and add the Put and Post action in the controller.

Comment: I just created new project with the same models and actions with my home computer.  something must be different I believe.  swagger give me an different error message. System.InvalidOperationException: Can't use schemaId "$Command" for type "$TestSwagger.EditModel+Command". The same schemaId is already used for type "$TestSwagger.CreateModel+Command"  And this error message make more sense. Yet, swagger should still allow nested parameter for two different actions with same inner class name.

Comment: There was an issue in 2015, but was just closed https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/pull/240

Answer (score 10):

By adding `c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);`

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TestSwagger", Version = "v1" });
                c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
            });
```

solved the schemaId conflict.  Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071513/swagger-error-conflicting-schemaids-duplicate-schemaids-detected-for-types-a-a)

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @HExit made my swagger page fail with following error:

> Resolver error at paths./api/v1/{sheetId}.get.requestBody.content.application/json.schema.$ref
> Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer: /components/schemas/XL.API.Features.Sheets.GetSheet+Command does not exist in document

It was fixed by changing it to

```
c.CustomSchemaIds(s => s.FullName.Replace("+", "."));
```